# Override NSScrollView in WebView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I made a custom NSScrollView with Pull to Refresh functionality in OSX. I would like to implement it in a WebView. is it possible to set a custom scroll view class for a (WebKit) WebView?

Comment: Is there any way you can make the pull to refresh control stand on its own?  It's completely dangerous to swap out something as big as WebKit's scroll view.